# Send control values between forms in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I need to send values of controls between forms in asp.net
I tried to send information with following URL:

DisplayNews.aspx?cmd=HyperLink1.value

And tried to recieve information with following code:

```
string s = Request.QueryString["cmd"];
```

But in output I see "HyperLink1.value" instead of real value.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        string url = "DisplayNews.aspx?cmd=" + HyperLink1.Text;
        Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

You can set your HyperLink1.NavigateUrl like this:

```
        HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "DisplayNews.aspx?cmd=" + HyperLink1.Text;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I want to send information whenever I click on a hyperlink. So I couldnt find where to put your code.

Comment: excuse me, I sent previous comment before I write every thing. so I edited that.

Comment: When I wanted to add new Web Form I clicked on "Put code in seperate file" option. It seems there is no Hyperlink1_click() in there to put that code.

Comment: If you are using core HyperLink control there is no "value" property. What have you planned to store in this property? Please check my edited answer.

Comment: By setting HyperLink1.NavigateUrl control will automaticly perform redirect to NavigateUrl on click event.

Comment: I checked your edited answer and I guess that I can solve problem with your code. But now my problem is I can not choose Hyperlink1_click from combobox in top of visual studio window. When I click on Hyperlink1 it brings me a code like this:         <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/DisplayNews.aspx?cmd=HyperLink1.value">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink> I dont know where to find hyperlink1_click

Comment: I have checked Hyperlink control and it actualy does not support click event by default. You should use NavigateUrl property. But you can use LinkButton instead. This one supports onclick event.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved. But please edit your answer. Its HyperLink1.TEXT not HyperLink1.value. thank you again